# Did any universe address the problem of double DNA

Tags: time-travel, paradox

When you mess up time travelling and become your own ancestor, there is a big problem:

> At some point in time, a child will be born with exactly the same DNA as you.

Did any franchise address this problem? Because, as far as I understand, your descendants don't have your DNA.

So, as an example, you are your own grandfather.

- You travel back in time with your DNA.
- You "make" one parent of yourself with his or her own DNA.
- Your parent "make" you and normally your DNA would be different thanthe one of all recent ancestors

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies

Comment: @Richard some people have weird fantasies xD

Comment: Why would two people with the same DNA be a problem? Identical twins don't cause the universe to implode.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins identical twins usually don't have the same dna. But after researching a bit, I learned that this difference develops after the birth. But only after John Sensebe's answer...

Comment: **This is essentially a "first of" question, although worded a little clunky. "First of" questions are on-topic.**

Comment: @CreationEdge I don't consider it a first-of question (at least anymore) since there was a false assumption.

Comment: I can still see it as one. You assume that it's a problem, but you could ask it as *What was the first time a time-travel work dealt with duplicate DNA?" and bam, there you go.

Comment: @CreationEdge OK, you're right. Should I reward it, or should I leave it?

Comment: Completely up to you, but as it's already got an answer (which I didn't see), editing the question now kind of invalidates it. I may VTC this now, and you're welcome to re-ask with the suggested format to get another type of answer.

Comment: What do you mean identical twins don't usually have the same DNA... That's literally what an identical twin is... Their DNA is identical because the fertilized egg split into two individual cells by accident instead of staying together like it was supposed to. Their DNA being identical has even been a problem in criminal cases where they couldn't prove which identical twin committed the crime.

Comment: @Probst in criminal cases, only a very small part of the DNA sequence is looked through. But during the lives of the twins they accumulate different mutations in their cells through different factors, eg cosmic rays.  Because of those the DNA differs later in life.

Comment: OK... Well their DNA was identical at the begging still. And in your case the two people would also have that happen...

Comment: @Probst yeah, and like I said in the comments already, wrong assumptions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not, in fact, a problem. Your DNA is made up of bits of the DNA of your ancestors, but you might coincidentally share bits of DNA with other people outside of your family. Yes, there might be people out there, in distant lands, with your nose.

Taken to its logical conclusion, this means that by an amazing coincidence, there might be another person out there with the exact same DNA as you. Which makes it possible, however unlikely, that one of your own ancestors shares the exact same DNA, and you wouldn't even know it.

If that's possible and non-problematic without time travel, then why would it be a problem with time travel?